# When testing TypeScript code, can we trust the declared types of parameters or should we test as if we're testing JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, types

I'm trying to test a method I've written in TypeScript. Let's say the method signature is as below:

```
doTask(value: number): void
```

Each method parameter is labeled with a type, but I'm worried that the caller will accidentally pass an argument of the wrong type into the method, as such:

```
let wrongValue: any = '3';
doTask(wrongValue);
```

Therefore, in my tests I want to try passing in arguments of the wrong type and checking to make sure my method doesn't fail silently. However, this requires a lot of extra testing for each parameter in the method and I'd have to do this for each method. It would be like testing JavaScript code.

I know I could strengthen my specification for this method and tell the caller that this method can ONLY be called with a number, but I don't want to put that much responsibility on the caller. I know I can also use type guards within my method, but I don't want to test based on the implementation.

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm wondering if there's some accepted practice in this situation? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where the parameter/value comes from. Typescript is there to prevent you from INTENTIONALY passing the wrong type. If the value comes from say a text input then you know its a string, hence you convert it to a number before you call the function.

Another concept is the concept of type guards that you implement. Read official [docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

**Edit**: Clarification: Typescript types are not available in javascript. The type specifications in typescript exist for your convinience. The parameter and return type declaration in your method is gone when compiled to javascript: `doTask(value: number /*<- this is removed in JS */): void /*<- this is removed in JS */`

e.g

```
function doTask(value: number) {
  //type of value passed is unknown at runtime?
  if(typeof value !== 'number') {
    // throw some error
  }

  //else continue 
}
```